# Help with preg_match_all, remove square braces

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make a function that take out the content in square braces but I can't remove the braces that I need to remove.

This is how it should look:

```
Hello [there] blabla
```

Turns into:

```
Hello <a href="http://blabla.com/index.php?id=there">linky</a> blabla
```

---

My current code:

```
$txt='Hello [there] blabla';

$re1='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
$re2='(\\[.*?\\])'; # Square Braces 1

if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1.$re2."/is", $txt, $matches))
{
    $sbraces1=$matches[1][0];
    print "<a href='http://blabla.com/index.php?id=$sbraces1'>Linky</a> \n";
}
```

My current code does this:

```
Hello [there] blabla
```

Turns into:

```
<a href='http://blabla.com/index.php?id=[there]'>Linky</a>
```

Comment: wouldnt it be better to use preg_replace that way you dont have to rebuild your string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) with this pattern:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

Here the part inside the brackets is grouped rather than the whole bracket with its content.

With `preg_replace_callback` you then can write a function that takes the match and turns it into a link:

```
function callback_linkify($match) {
    return '<a href="http://example.com/index.php?id='.urlencode($match[1]).'">Linky</a>';
}
```

And the use of that pattern and the callback function:

```
$output = preg_replace_callback('/\[(.*?)\]/', 'callback_linkify', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

EDIT:

```
<?php
$string = 'Hello [there] blabla';
$re2='(\\[)([^\\]]*)(\\])'; # Square Braces 1
$pattern = "/".$re2."/is";
$replacement = '<a href="http://blabla.com/index.php?id=$2">linky</a>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Comment: Please don't post answers consisting solely of links to other sites.  It's okay to include links to pastebin sites, but your answer should make sense without them.  If the code is too long to post here (and yours isn't), extract the most important parts and add some explanatory text.

Comment: @Alan Moore, I would post the code here but whenever I place the code in pre and code tags bits of the code disapears. Placing the code in services such as PastBin is the only way I can guarantee that all the code is preserved

Comment: SO's got that covered with Markdown: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  The syntax coloring in indented code blocks is kinda haphazard, but it preserves whitespace doesn't drop characters.  Inline code formatting with `backticks` normalizes whitespace and has trouble with certain characters (e.g. backslashes), but it can be used in comments as well as in regular posts.

Comment: @Alan Moore - Yes I've already read this a number of times. Even if I create a code block and paste my HTML the code block strips half of it out.

Comment: You may be doing things in the wrong order.  You're supposed to paste the text in, select it all, and *then* press control-K.  Each line of the code block has to start with at least four spaces, and the whole block has to be separated from the surrounding text by at least one blank line.

Comment: Ah haaa, got it now ;) will update my post to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the part *between* the brackets in a backreference:

```
\[([^\]]*)\]
```

and then use the first backreference instead of the whole match in its place.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to match the square brackets and the inner content you can try using something like this:

`"(\\[)([^\\]]*)(\\])"`

I just hope I properly escaped the brackets.

Comment: Unless you need to reference the brackets individually afterwards there is no need to put them into individual groups.

Comment: @Joey i agree. I just wasn't sure if he'd rather do a replace on the brackets rather than on the entire matched string.